# Parsing with SimpleHTMLPArser

Tags: php, parsing

Folks,

I am using SIMPLEHTMLPARSER.

I am not able to parse HTML, When i var_dump the html document, it just shows the DOM structure and no HTML content.

```
$produrl = 'http://wap.ebay.com/Pages/ViewItem.aspx?aid=160586179890&sv=160586179890/';

var_dump(file_get_html($produrl));




   $html = file_get_html($produrl);
    var_dump($html->find('div[id=Teaser_Item] img[src]', 0));
```

Actually, what i want to extract is the IMG SRC which is:

http://wap.ebay.com/Pages/RbHttpHandler.ashx?width=51&height=240&fsize=999000&format=jpg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ebayimg.com%2F00%2F%24%28KGrHqN%2C!jEE2n%28iTLozBNwBPG0bUg~~0_1.JPG%3Fset_id%3D8800005007

can someone help me debugging this, please?

Cheers
Natasha Thomas

Comment: div[id=Teaser_Item] -- did you try putting Teaser_Item in double quotes?

Comment: Dear Pete, when i add "Teaser_Item", var_dump gives NULL. :-(

Comment: That code doesn't define what `$html` is.  Do you have error_reporting turned on with notices enabled?  Should it be `$html = file_get_html ( $produrl );`

Comment: Dear Judda, i have updated my Code as you said, still it does not Output the HTML Content, but just an Exmpty DOM Structure.

Comment: Hey ya DT, i am using WAMP latest version so i think the PHP is PHP 5.2.0 there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
 require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

 $produrl = 'http://wap.ebay.com/Pages/ViewItem.aspx?aid=160586179890&sv=160586179890/';

 // Grab the document
 $html = file_get_html($produrl);

 // Find the img tag in the Teaser_Item div
 $a = $html->find('div[id=Teaser_Item] img', 0);

 // Display the src
 echo($a->attr['src']);

 ?>
```

Comment: When i run this code, i get this Error:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\wamp\www\domp\ebay_img_src.php on line 13         & Line 13 is  echo($a->attr['src']);      I must Mention i am testing it on my Localhost with WAMP.

Comment: Did you adjust the require_once to be your path?