# simple html dom scraping large html file

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, file-get-contents

I need to scrape a large html file (eg: http://www.indianrail.gov.in/mail_express_trn_list.html) using simple html dom. I started with a simple script:

```
<?php
require "simple_html_dom.php";
echo file_get_html('http://www.indianrail.gov.in/mail_express_trn_list.html')->plaintext;
?>
```

which shows nothing, just a blank page with the error message in Apache error.log file

```
 PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/index.php on line 3
 PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/index.php on line 3
```

at the same time all other pages (eg: http://www.indianrail.gov.in/special_trn_list.html) works fine with the same script.

Comment: Have you tried using `file_get_contents` instead of `file_get_html`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: i am able to replicate the issue, i will dig deeper and let u know

Comment: @Fred i tried , but the same error..

Comment: @DevZer0 Waiting for reply .. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @krizna These answers on SO may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/a/6006379/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6519443/1415724

Comment: @krizna Are you trying to find/fetch a particular element from within that URL?

Comment: @Fred trying to get <TD CLASS="TABLE_BORDER_BOTH_LEFT"> values

Comment: @krizna Have you followed the example from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6006379/1415724 ? Seems that your (posted) code is not passing query to what you're trying to fetch. How are you defining your query?

Comment: @Fred but this one **echo file_get_html('www.indianrail.gov.in/special_trn_list.html')->plaintext;** works fine ..

Comment: @krizna Yes but how are you expecting to find `<TD CLASS="TABLE_BORDER_BOTH_LEFT">` if you're not telling it to find `<TD CLASS="TABLE_BORDER_BOTH_LEFT">`? You're only passing paramter as `->plaintext`. Unless there's something about the library I am not aware of, on how to set it to look for the content in question.

Comment: @krizna Visit http://stackoverflow.com/a/6006379/1415724 and copy the code from there and then replace `http://wap.ebay.com/Pages/ViewItem.aspx?aid=160586179890&sv=160586179890/` with `http://www.indianrail.gov.in/mail_express_trn_list.html`, then replace `div[id=Teaser_Item] img` with `<TD CLASS="TABLE_BORDER_BOTH_LEFT">` then tell me if that worked or not.

Comment: @Fred the given **http://wap.ebay.com/Pages/ViewItem.aspx?aid=160586179890&sv=160586179890/** itself is not working . can you pls tell me any other page

Comment: @krizna You have to replace the Ebay URL with the URL you posted. Plus, I doubt eBay will let itself get scraped, just like Google. Probably why it's not working. Have you not tried it with YOUR URL?

Comment: define('MAX_FILE_SIZE',12600000); in the simple_html_dom.php file fixed this issue .. thanks @Fred

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue appears to be `MAX_FILE_SIZE` defined in `simple_html_dom`.

you can adjust it by editing `define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);` line in simple_html_dom.php file.

Comment: i tried define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000000000000000); .. but no luck .. still the same error .. thanks

Comment: define a realistic number, i set it to 12600000

Comment: it seams working , but i'm getting different error now ..  exit signal Segmentation fault (11)