# How to trigger class autoload?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, autoloader

The particular class I'm talking about is `HtmlDomParser` of `sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser` package. It contains only static methods, which I don't want to call. `new ReflectionClass()` doesn't do the trick. `class_exists(..., TRUE)` neither.

Comment: What is the point of it? Or your class file has side effects?

Comment: It defines [a constant](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser/blob/v1.5.0/Src/Sunra/PhpSimple/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php#L65) which I want to [redefine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939101/simple-html-dom-scrapping-large-html-file) without changing package code and trigerring notices.

Comment: You could register your own autoloader especially for this case and "catch" this case.

Comment: Isn't it like tying my code to `composer`'s implementation? Can you show the code? Why especially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, forgot to specify namespace. These all methods work out:

```
$autoloader = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
class_exists('Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser');
new ReflectionClass('Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser');
$autoloader->loadClass('Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser');
```